# OracleSQL CASE Statement on Number in string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called TEST_TABLE with 1 column called COLUMN1. This table has 2 records:

```
V.WEEKLY_2020_15
V.WEEKLY_2020_16
```

I'm trying to write a `CASE statement` that maps these records to different Periods. e.g.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN COLUMN1='V.WEEK_2020_ **MAXIMUM NUMBER** ' THEN 'CURRENT PERIOD' 
ELSE 'HISTORICAL PERIOD 1' END
FROM TEST_TABLE
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to do this though. I need to get the number from the end of the string, and then compare it to the other numbers in the table. Once it finds one number that is higher or lower it can stop the search as there will always only be 2 numbers in this table.

Comment: You would need to do a substring or parse to get the last 2 numbers first then apply logic or your case statement.  Is the format always 2 digits for your last 2 numbers?  Or can it be 1 or 3 digits (it would change how to write the logic)

Comment: How do you know what the maximum number is?  The maximum in the table? If so, why 2020?  The year (at least where I am now) is 2021.

Comment: A table with a single column sounds highly unlikely.  And having a column where a substring of the column value has business meaning in and of itself is almost always a design flaw. I'm suspecting there's much more to this, and you have over-simplified to focus on your pre-conceived solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number from the end of the string with a regular expression. This one gets the 3rd group of characters which don't include an underscore.

```
select column1, regexp_substr(column1,'[^_]+',1,3) from test_table;
```

Alternately you could get the 2nd group of numbers with `regexp_substr(column1,'[0-9]+',1,2)`. The best regexp will depend on your knowledge of the possible string values. If you know the number will always be the last 2 characters, you could do `substr(column1, -2)`

And if you want to identify rows which have the highest/lowest/etc value, adding a column which applies an window/analytical function is a common pattern.

```
-- sample data
with test_table as (select 'V.WEEKLY_2020_15' as column1 from dual 
                    union select 'V.WEEKLY_2020_16' from dual)
-- query
SELECT column1, regexp_substr(column1,'[^_]+',1,3) as regex, max_number, 
    CASE WHEN COLUMN1=max_number THEN 'CURRENT PERIOD' 
    ELSE 'HISTORICAL PERIOD 1' END as period
FROM (select test_table.*, 
      max(column1) over (order by regexp_substr(column1,'[^_]+',1,3) desc) as max_number 
      from test_table) T;
```

Usually the data will be more complicated then you're showing - for example, you might have 2 periods in the table *for each primary key*, and then you'll want to partition your window function.

```
-- sample data
with test_table as (select 1 as pk, 'V.WEEKLY_2020_15' as column1 from dual 
                    union select 1, 'V.WEEKLY_2020_16' from dual
                    union select 2, 'V.WEEKLY_2021_1' from dual 
                    union select 2, 'V.WEEKLY_2021_200' from dual)
-- query
SELECT pk, column1, regexp_substr(column1,'[^_]+',1,3) as regex, 
    CASE WHEN COLUMN1=max_number THEN 'CURRENT PERIOD' 
    ELSE 'HISTORICAL PERIOD 1' END as period
FROM (select test_table.*, 
      max(column1) over (partition by pk order by regexp_substr(column1,'[^_]+',1,3) desc) as max_number 
      from test_table) T;
```

Output:

| PK | COLUMN1 | REGEX | PERIOD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | V.WEEKLY_2020_16 | 16 | CURRENT PERIOD |
| 1 | V.WEEKLY_2020_15 | 15 | HISTORICAL PERIOD 1 |
| 2 | V.WEEKLY_2021_200 | 200 | CURRENT PERIOD |
| 2 | V.WEEKLY_2021_1 | 1 | HISTORICAL PERIOD 1 |